# Android Studio cannot find my JDK

Tags: linux, android-studio, java

I have Android Studio installed on my Linux Mint 15 machine and I am trying to use it with LibGDX. In LibGDX I have created a project with intelliJ selected in the advanced creation menu. In Android Studio, when I go to Configure>Project Defaults>Project Structure, The JDK Location is blank and it says at the bottom "Please choose a valid JDK directory." I have OpenJDK installed, and when I run `java -version` in a terminal it returns:

```
"java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)"
```

When I type `javac -version` in a terminal that returns:

```
"javac 1.7.0_80"
```

When I open the project I created in LibGDX in Android Studio it says at the bottom:

```
"Error: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: /home/myname/Android/Sdk/bin/java"
```

I have added the JAVA_HOME environment variable to my profile file and have even tried pasting the java executable in said `"/home/myname/Android/Sdk/bin/java"`folder but it still returns the same error. If anyone knows a fix please let me know! Thank you.

EDIT:
My issue has been resolved! Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you try with `oracle jdk`?

Comment: Do you also have Java 1.6 installed separately? I believe I read that you actually have to have 1.6 as a separate install than 1.7 or 1.8 in order for IntelliJ to work. Don't know if that will help you

Comment: I installed OpenJDK 6 as well but I still have the same issue. I tried Oracle's JDK but it still wouldn't accept it.

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: Also: a useful trick I learned for setting JAVA_HOME: Put this in your .profile: `export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -e /usr/bin/java)))` (This may be Ubuntu-specific)

Comment: please anyone can help this

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it this way:
in the global gradle setting, use local gradle distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A little old but on my Windows 10 Machine I got the problem resolved after pointing to the 32Bit Version of the JDK. By default the Android Studio took the 64Bit one which didn't work for me.

So simply change the path to the 32Bit Version or install a 64Bit Version of the Android Studio if there is one, I did not check on that.